# How to "contramap" akka-streams Sink

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Having an *akka-streams* `Sink`:

```
val sink: Sink[Foo, Any] = ???
```

and a function from `Bar` to `Foo`:

```
val f: Bar => Foo = ???
```

I want to *contramap* (the opposite of *map*) `sink` with `f` to get a sink of type `Sink[Bar, Any]`, but can't find such a simple method in the library. How to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be rather simple.

Create a `Flow` accepting `Bar`s:

```
val flow: Flow[Bar, Bar, Unit] = Flow[Bar]
```

and map it with `f` pipelining results to the original `sink`:

```
val sink2: Sink[Bar, Unit] = flow.map(f).to(sink)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `akka-streams` version `2.4.X` it is even simpler:

```
val sink3: Sink[Bar, Future[Done]] = sink.contramap(f)
```